# Is it possible to simulate a d20 roll using smaller dice?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

I'm wondering if it's possible to simulate a d20 using smaller dice, and if so, how would one figure out how many you would need?

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2506174/simulate-a-n-dice) provides an algorithm to do so using 2 coins with `p = 1/2` and `p = 1/n`, but is there an algorithm that would work for multiple like dice of the same probability? eg. can you find an `x` such that if you roll `x` 6 sided dice you are left with exactly 20 distinct outcomes?

Comment: If you have fair dice with sides $d_1,d_2,\cdots ,d_n$ then the only way to get $20$ equally likely results is if $d_1d_2\cdots d_n$ is divisible by $20.$ In particular, one of the die must have a number of sides a multiple of $5.$

Comment: Well, with a ten sided die you can toss it once to determine if you are in $(1,\cdots, 10)$ or $(11,\cdots, 20)$ and then again to determine where you are in that collection.  Similarly you can toss a five sided die four times, and so on.

Comment: You can combine a single d5 and d4 using [the Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem). Or, more simply, if $x$ is a uniformly distributed rv on $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ and $y$ a uniformly distributed rv from $\{0,1,2,3\}$, then $5y+x$ has a uniform distribution over $\{0,1,\ldots,19\}$. Subtract/add one, if the range is off by one.

Comment: A bit off topic, but I remember [Matt Parker posing the challenge problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHh0ui5mi_E) of simulating a roll of two six-sided dice using three indistinguishable six-sided dice.

Comment: In regards to lulu's comment, this is actually very standard practice.  In tabletop games it is common to not own a 100-sided die (*I do have one in my collection, but it is so close to spherical that it rolls for a very long time*) and to instead use two 10-sided dice to simulate a 100-sided die.  The first 10-sided die will represent the tens-digit while the second 10-sided die will represent the ones-digit.  See [percentile dice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice_notation#Percentile_dice_(d%)) on wikipedia.

Comment: @lulu  Sorry, can you flesh out your idea the 5sided die case? The only thing I can think of at the moment is that the first roll determines if you are in 1-4, 5-8, 9-12,13-16,17-20.

Comment: I think this question has the most comprehensive answers for a $10$ sided dice. It surely can be adapted to a $20$ sided dice.https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1314460/how-to-generate-a-random-number-between-1-and-10-with-a-six-sided-die?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Keshav  Yes, you're right.  It doesn't work as smoothly for a five sided die as I thought.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen is there a general form of your Chinese remainder theorem result for generating a uniform distribution over {0, 1, ..., c} from a function of uniform rv's from {0,1,...,a} and {0,1,..,b} where a<c and b<c?

Comment: @MarkAJohnson On second thought the use of Chinese remainder theorem was quite unnecessary. Just use the formula $(b+1)x+y$ if $x\in\{0,1,2,\ldots,a\}$ and $b\in\{0,1,\ldots,b\}$. You get $N=(a+1)(b+1)$ alternative outcomes. If $m$ is any factor of $N$, then taking the result modulo $m$ still gives equally likely outcomes.

Comment: Related: [How to generate a random number between 1 and 10 with a six-sided die?(]https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1314460/how-to-generate-a-random-number-between-1-and-10-with-a-six-sided-die)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you aim for a fixed number $x$ of dice, I agree with the comment of Thomas Andrews that the product of the numbers of their sides has to be a multiple of $20$. However, if the number $x$ may vary, then this algorithm provides a solution:

1. Roll a 6-sided die with outcome $\omega_1$. Set $a_1=0$, if $\omega_1\in\{1,2,3\}$, and $a_1=10$ otherwise.
2. Roll a 6-sided die with outcome $\omega_2$. Set $a_2=0$, if $\omega_2\in\{1,2,3\}$, and $a_2=5$ otherwise.
3. Roll a 6-sided die with outcome $\omega_3$. Set $a_3=\omega_3$, if $\omega_3\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. If $\omega_3 = 6$ repeat step 3.

Eventually, the algorithm will terminate and $a = a_1 + a_2 + a_3$ will be uniformly distributed in $\{1,\dots,20\}$.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, you can use a single $(6)$ sided die (or one red die and one green one) to **fairly** simulate a $(19)$ sided die, as follows:

Roll the die until you get a number less than $(6)$.  Denote the *satisfying* roll as $(r_1)$.  Then roll the die again until you get less than $(5)$.  Denote this roll as $(r_2)$.  Then compute $T_1 = [4 \times (r_1 - 1)] + (r_2)$.  As has already been discussed, $T_1$ is equally likely to be assigned any of the numbers in $\{1,2,\cdots, 20\}.$

Now, repeat the exact same procedure, computing $T_2$.  If $T_2 = T_1$, reject $T_2$ and compute $T_2$ from scratch.  Finally, once $T_2 \neq T_1$, for $T_2 > T_1$, set $T_2 = T_2 - 1.$

Note that the objection that it theoretically could take an *unbounded* number of rolls until $T_2$ is determined also applies to the original procedure of emulating a $(20)$ sided die.  That is, it theoretically could take an unbounded number of rolls until you roll $< (6)$.

To verify that this procedure works, the case of $T_1 = 1$ or $T_1 = 20$ is trivial.

Consider 1 < $T_1 < 20$.  Then, consider the computation of $T_2$, once $T_2 \neq T_1$, and **before** $T_2$ is adjusted to ($T_2 - 1 ~:~$ if necessary).  The $(19)$ possible values of $T_2$ represented by
$\{1,\cdots, (T_1 - 1), (T_1 + 1), \cdots, 20\}$ are equally likely.  This is because $T_1$ was computed *at random*.

Then, the final computation of $T_2$ will be represented by *shifting* $\{(T_1 + 1), \cdots, 20\}$ down $(1)$ if the unadjusted value of $T_2$ happened to be $> T_1$.